# Bootstrap 5 - 5 equal columns break down to two rows centered on medium devices

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

On desktop sizes I have 5 equal width columns that are spaced evenly. On mobile I will break down to 1 column and then on medium sizes I want it to break down into two rows with the bottom row evenly spaced and centered below the top row like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with Bootstrap 5 built-in classes or would I have to add some custom CSS to make this possible? Here's what I have so far:

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
.row .col-6 {
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, what that does is align the 4th column directly below the 1st column and the 5th column directly below the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "On mobile I will break down to 1 column and then on medium sizes I
> want it to break down into two rows"

Make sure you use `col-12` to get a single column on mobile and then simply `justify-content-center` the row...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/Duijj4Y4MO)

But, you didn't specify if you want 2 rows on *md and wider*, or *only on md*. If you want 2 rows on md and wider this use specific column sizes like `col-md-4`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**.justify-content-md-evenly**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) and [**.row-cols**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns) variations.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row [class^="col"],
.row [class*=" col"] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-auto text-center justify-content-between justify-content-md-evenly">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```